# Firebase cloud function generate empty pdf files

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, node-pdfkit

I wrote a firebase cloud function which is generating pdf files using node's pdfkit module. But files uploaded to cloud storage don't have any page. I don't know weather problem is with pdfkit, directory or pip. Here is a complete code of my function.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as PDFDocument from 'pdfkit'
import *  as  fs from 'fs'
import *  as mkdirp from 'mkdirp-promise'
import *  as path from 'path'
import * as os from 'os'

admin.initializeApp();

export const downloadPdf = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
  const acc = data.accountNo;
  const bank = data.bank;
  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  const filePath = "PDF_A"+Date.now()+".pdf";
  const baseFileName = path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath));
  const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
  const PDFFilePath = path.normalize(path.format({dir: fileDir, name: baseFileName, ext: '.pdf'}));
  const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
  const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
  const tempLocalPDFFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), PDFFilePath);
  await mkdirp(tempLocalDir);
  const pdfStream = fs.createWriteStream(tempLocalFile);


  doc.pipe(pdfStream);

  try {
      const dataSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(`/Transactions/${bank}/${acc}`).once('value');

       doc.fontSize(18);

       doc.text('Transactions',100,100).moveDown();
       dataSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
           doc.fontSize(14);
           //Using a standard PDF font
           doc.text(`Transaction     id:${childSnapshot.key}`,100,100).moveDown();
           return false
       });

       doc.end();
       const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
       await pdfStream.addListener('finish', function() {
           // HERE PDF FILE IS DONE

       });

       await bucket.upload(tempLocalPDFFile, { destination: PDFFilePath    });
       fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalPDFFile);
       fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
       return { url: 'someurl' };

       //console.log('PDF uploaded to Storage at', PDFFilePath);


       } catch (error) {
             //throw new functions.https.HttpsError('Unknown', error.message);
       return { url: error.message };
       }
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does `pdfStream.addListener` return?  Your code suggests it returns a promise, but I suspect it does not.

Comment: Problem was with pdfkit. I just used `const doc = new PDFDocument({compress:false});` and it solved my problem. Thanks for your comment @DougStevenson